# If statments effect classes, not just objects

Tags: python

I am making walls in Pygame, I plan on making a lot of walls in the game but making individual if statements for each block of wall doesn't sound that efficient.
Is there a way I could make an if statement that just effects the whole class of wall? Right now it looks like this (wall is a class and player is an object)

```py
if wall.x == player.x and wall.y == player.y
    player.y -= 64
```

Comment: Please update your question with, at least, some basic information about the `player` and `wall` classes, especially their `x` and `y` members.

Comment: There's no way to magically check something against every single wall, you'll have to iterate different walls. However there are algorithmic solutions to reduce the number of walls you test. E.g. you can split the level into chunks, e.g. 100x100 pixels, then for each chunk you create a list with walls that are inside this chunk. Now to check if you collide anything you can find at which chunk your player is (e.g. `chunk_x=player.x / 100`, similar for `chunk_y`), then you check against all walls in this chunk (which is presumably  **much** smaller number than all the walls on the level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a list of walls, and perform the check in a loop on all of them:

```py
walls = [wall_1, wall_2, ...]

for wall in walls:
    if wall.x == player.x and wall.y == player.y
        player.y -= 64
```

Comment: Regarding your edit @Tokerikoo, would love to learn how that can be done.

Comment: Kinda like the other answer here. You can have a static list of instances inside the class and then have a `@classmethod` do something on all those instances so you just do something like `if Wall.collides(player): player.y -= 64`. It is basically your code wrapped inside a method...

Answer (score 1):

If think you can handle it like this.

```
class Wall:
    _instances = []

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._instances.append(self)

    @classmethod
    def checking_method(cls, x, y):
        for wall in cls._instances:
            yield wall.x == x and wall.y == y


for check in Wall.checking_method(player.x, player.y):
    if check:
        player.y -= 64
```

Not sure if this is the most performatic way though.